# How to extract string with one regex?

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

I need some help with regex. I have 3 types of headings

- `1.1.1.1 Abc`
- `B.1.1.1 Abc`
- `B. Abc`

And I want to select like to select them like this

- `1.1.1.1`
- `B.1.1.1`
- `B`

Thank you

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem yourself?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: yes, i spent so much time with it, i created something like this : ^(\d|[A-Z])+(\.(\d|\.))|(\d\.)|^(\d\s)|^([A-Z]\.)+\s, but its not working properly

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Its for Nintex workflow

Comment: Try `^[A-Z0-9](?:\.\d)*\.?(?!\S)` or `^[A-Z0-9]+(?:\.\d+)*\.?(?!\S)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[0-9\.A-Z\/]*?(?=\.?\s)
```

Comment: Excellent work, this works without any problems, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex pattern whose matches seem to work for what you expect:

```
^.*?(?=\.? [A-Za-z]{3}$)
```

The lookahead will cause the pattern to stop matching when it sees an optional dot, followed by a space, then followed by three characters and the end of the line.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try groups

```js
var examples = [
  "1.1.1.1 Abc",
  "B.1.1.1 Abc",
  "B. Abc"
];

for(var k in examples) {
  k = examples[k];
  document.write(k.replace(/(.*)Abc/,'$1')+"<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern: `([\dA-Z]\.)+[\dA-Z]?`

`([\dA-Z]\.)+` will match ne or more uppercase letter or digits followed by a dot.

`[\dA-Z]?` will match zero or one occurence of uppercase letter or digits followed by a dot.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxv1nj/1)

Comment: This would match `B.1.1.1.` which perhaps the OP does not want to match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For me exactly this issue is not clear to me, I assumed that he wants to match that. Neverthelesss, he can alter this pattern easily, to not match such strings. But good point, anyway. Thanks :)